# Mongo aggregation project arrays intersection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents where each of the documents may have an array of `teamsIds` like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "teamsIds": ["team_a", "team_b"]
}
```

I'm trying to write an Aggregation (doing $match stage before) that will $project the documents and return objects like:

```
{ 
  "id": 1,
  "matchingFilter": true
}
```

where `matchingFilter` should be true when teamsIds does contain any of the teams I'm checking for. In the case of the document above, I need `matchingFilter` to be `true` when searching for teams: ["team_c", "team_a"] because it has assigned "team_a". What would be the simplest way to achieve it? I can't use `$elemMatch` in the Aggregation pipeline, is there an equivalent I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical implementation of your expected set intersection behaviour is using `$setIntersection`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      // your match here
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "id": 1,
      "matchingFilter": {
        "$ne": [
          [],
          {
            "$setIntersection": [
              {
                "$ifNull": [
                  "$teamsIds",
                  []
                ]
              },
              // your input array here
              [
                "team_c",
                "team_a"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aMBNgal_0-5)

Comment: Thank you, this is mostly covering what I need but is not handling the case where teamsIds property does not exist on the document at all. I could wrap that with $and and check also whether the property $exists but this operator is also not available in aggregations.

Comment: @enterbios An easy fix would be using `$ifNull` to safeguard the non-existing field and fallback to an empty array. Updated the answer.